# Use the double angle formula to find $2\cos^{2}\left(-\frac{\pi}{8}\right)-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use the double angle formula to find $2\cos^{2}\left(-\frac{\pi}{8}\right)-1$?

I tried $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-1$ which equals square root of $2$. But when I checked my textbook, the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Does this expression remind you of the *right hand side* of any identity you know??

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1$ so your answer is $\cos(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$